# Best approach implementing server-side logic with some sort of TaskManager class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm usually coding in Node, but want to try Spring Boot and before I start a project I want to build, I wanted to ask for best approaches to save time.

My project requires some sort of Manager class that manages a set of custom classes I am going to code, for example an AnimalManager that manages a bunch of Animal.class objects.

All Animals are using websockets to receive data from third party APIs. I need some Manager class to handle all these Animals and call their functions based on custom intervals etcetera.

What I am confused about now is how to implement such Manager classes that need to start working after start up without instantiation. From my understanding @Service is more like business logic for database operations. Is there some equivalent for Manager classes or standalone classes that don't interact with databases or controllers and are meant to just run tasks?

Comment: You can use `@Service`, or just plain `@Component`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring's `CommandLineRunner`. It will be executed after startup when everything is initialized and ready. See: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        // TODO implementation of your task manager
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this would be just a huge function if I put everything inside of that. I wanted a seperate class like XYManager

Comment: That's no problem. Just create a new Spring Bean class and implement that interface (`@Component public class BitQueen implements CommandLineRunner...`). With help of the `run` method, you are able to start/init/trigger something in your manager or to start a worker thread. Now it depends on what exactly you would like to manage?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if the manager runs continuously or not (in a loop), also if the animals are hard coded or not and if those intervals are configurable at runtime or not..
but perhaps this helps :

You could create a component (for your manager) with a @PostConstruct that start doing your stuff then (after bootup) https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy.

You can also call methods at certain intervals with
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

It is also possible the animals don't need a Manager and are components that just react to incoming messages.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. A service later would need to have access to the manager to retrieve the objects if needed. The objects handled by the Manager class should retrieve 3rd party data in realtime.

Comment: Sounds like your manager needs to be a simple Spring Bean (`@Component`). Per default, it is a singleton instance. And what about the managed objects? Do they receive data by websocket communication? Is only one instance of them required, or one instance per websocket connection?

Comment: yes the objects managed are all connected via websockets to the 3rd party API. There can be several thousand objects of that class that need to be managed / stored inside the manager class.

Comment: when I annotate the Manager as @Component, will it automatically call the constructor on start up so I can have an init method inside the constructor to get everything going?

Comment: yes of course. But don't add logic in the constructor. Put it in the PostConstruct.

Comment: But also, dont add state in your components. They should be stateless.